# Oauth implemetation for Command line application

Tags: python, linux, oauth, gitlab

I have successfully implemented the Ouath in a command line application it is working perfectly, but the basic need is a client ID and client segregation, so I want to store gitlabs them in an efficient way in my local environment. I have implemented an env file, but in the user perspective, I want to hide that client ID and client segregation. Is there a way to store them securely in Linux OS? This has worked in my development, But how can I store them on the client side?
`gitlab` `oauth` `cli`

```
def load_env(file_path="wglib/auth.env"):
    try:
        with open(file_path, "r") as file:
            lines = file.readlines()
            for line in lines:
                parts = line.strip().split("=")
                if len(parts) == 2:
                    key, value = parts
                    os.environ[key] = value
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print(f"The .env file ({file_path}) was not found.")


load_env()
CLIENT_ID = os.getenv("clientid")
CLIENT_SECRET = os.getenv("cliendserect")
```

this is worked of in my development but how can store in client side very serect

I need to store the client id and client serect in secure way in linux`